# Is there a way to debug an already running application compiled in release mode?

Tags: .net, windows-services, debugging, release-mode

I have a dotnet windows service that's currently hung, but running. Is there anyway to attach a debugger to it, despite the lack of symbols; and that it's already running?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ignore the "no symbols" warning. Once you have a native debugger attached (i prefer WinDbg for stuff like this), then load up the SoS tool pack:

```
.loadby sos mscorwks
```

Now you can get a managed callstack using the `!clrstack` command, and hope that gives you enough information to figure out the hang. Here's [a handy cheat-sheet](https://web.archive.org/web/20201024041713/http://geekswithblogs.net/.NETonMyMind/archive/2006/03/14/72262.aspx) with a few others if that doesn't do it for you.

Won't help you this time, but... get in the habit of turning on symbol file generation for debug *and* release-mode builds. There's no reason not to, and it'll make your life a bit easier in situations like this.

Comment: I just want to second that you should be doing symbol file generation for debug and release builds.

Answer (score 2):

From MS dev IDE
Debug -> Processes -> Attach (After you choose a process.)  You might have to click the "show system processes" box.  There may be no useful information though...

Comment: Don't you get a no debug symbols can be found for this process?

Comment: And yes you can list a service that way as long as it's in its own process.

Comment: If there are no symbols, yes.  But if you want to step through the assembler code you can.

Comment: This would be a good idea for a compiled exe where you could get a stack trace and link the it to somewhere in the original code, but I can't see what usable info he could get from a "jit" compiled .net app (just guessing here, I never tried it so correct me if I'm wrong)

Answer (score 2):

Here is sample code, links to tools, and presentations on [how to debug a hung .NET process](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/pages/net-debugging-demos-information-and-setup-instructions.aspx).

You probably also want to watch [this video presentation](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/MSDNSweden/Vanliga-fel-som-grs-med-ASPNET-och-hur-du-hittar-dem-med-WinDbg/), which features the same tools and samples. Despite the Swedish text on the web page, the video is in English.